# Change the background of a circle periodically with css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 3 circles created with CSS.

I want to change the color of each circle every 3 seconds.

```
3 Seconds -> 1 Circle Color goes Orange
6 Seconds -> 2 Circle Color goes Orange
9 Seconds -> 3 Circle Color goes Orange
12 Seconds -> 1,2,3 Circle Color goes White

15 Seconds -> 1 Circle Color goes Orange
18 Seconds -> 2 Circle Color goes Orange
21 Seconds -> 3 Circle Color goes Orange
24 Seconds -> 1,2,3 Circle Color goes White
```

This is the loop. The problem I am having is that at 12 seconds not all of the circles go white. I am using the set Interval function for doing this.

```
this.boton1 = function(){
  var container = document.getElementById('circle1');
  container.style.background = '#FF7700';
};  

this.boton4 = function(){
  var container = document.getElementById('circle1');
  container.style.background = '#FFFFFF';
};

setInterval(boton1,3000);
setInterval(boton4,12000);
```

I am guessing I am managing wrong this with the set Interval. 
I have a [DEMO HERE](http://jsbin.com/OjEfUCU/5) showing the results.

Thanks in advance

**Update**

In case someone need the solution. Here is the [DEMO update](http://jsbin.com/olAYIna/1)

Comment: Use just one setInterval call with a counter, not two intervals that will create a race condition.

Comment: demo isnt showing anything......Uncaught ReferenceError: o is not defined 5:54
Uncaught ReferenceError: remoteWindow is not defined

Comment: I update the link. It was my error on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble is that you are using setInterval.
It means that every 3 seconds circles go orange. But 12 % 3=0. And no one knows what will act the first setInterval(..,12000) or setInterval(..,3000).
Change 12000 to 12500 or, imho, use setTimeout(sample,3000)
where sample like this

```
function sample(){
  counter++;
  if (counter % 4 ==0){
    //circles go white
  } else {
    //circles go orange
  }
  setTimeout(sample,3000);
}
```